# select records with matching criteria in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a SQL table `table1`

```
+--------------------------+
| id | person |   eats     |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |   1    |   apple    |
|  2 |   3    |  banana    |    
|  3 |   2    |  orange    |
|  4 |   1    | strawberry |
|  5 |   2    |   grapes   |
|  6 |   4    |   apple    |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I want to get all persons who eat both `apple` and say `strawberry`.

I tried

```
select person 
from table1
where eats in( 'apple', 'strawberry' )
```

but this query returns `1, 1, 4`, which I guess is because, it is checking  against `apple` and `strawberry` seperately.

How can get all persons who eat both `apple` and `strawberry` ?

Comment: Can the same person have two apple rows?

Comment: No. the table will have unique entries for each person and fruit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT person 
FROM table1
WHERE eats IN( 'apple', 'strawberry' )
GROUP BY person
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT eats)=2
```

**Update** To me the query explains itself. But since you ask for explanation lets try together:

your original query return this result:

```
1
1
4
```

But you don't want to get 1 twice, that means you should group result by `person`, that bring us to next query:

```
SELECT person 
FROM table1
WHERE eats IN( 'apple', 'strawberry' )
GROUP BY person
```

which will return:

```
1
4
```

but you don't want `person=4` because it only match `apple`, so the simpliest way to reach that to me is to count distinct `eats` like:

```
SELECT person, count(distinct eats)
FROM table1
WHERE eats IN( 'apple', 'strawberry' )
GROUP BY person
```

then we have this result:

```
person  count(distinct eats)
1        2
4        1
```

and we are ready to filter this resultset to get only those who have 2 (apple and strawberry):

```
SELECT person, count(distinct eats)
FROM table1
WHERE eats IN( 'apple', 'strawberry' )
GROUP BY person
HAVING count(distinct eats) = 2
```

this will return:

```
person  count(distinct eats)
1        2
```

But you did not ask for `count` that is why I've removed `count(distinct eats)` part from `SELECT`ed fields list.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea612/6

Comment: thanks @Alex :) just a short question. Can you please explain how this works ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) Actually I was confused about the `GROUP BY person` part, `But you don't want to get 1 twice, that means you should group result by person` : why won't `distinct` work here ?

Answer (score 3):

Group by `person` and take only those having **both** records in the group

```
select person 
from table1
where eats in( 'apple', 'strawberry' )
group by person
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: LOL ... looked like you typed in a hurry